# How to print the values of a dictionary-like StringBuffer in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, stringbuffer

I have this code :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try {
   BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
      System.out.println(line);
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the line :

```
System.out.println(line);
```

prints in console at the end of the loop like this:

```
{"signupname":"John","signuppassword":"1234","signupnickname":"Jonny",    
"signupdescription":"student","signupphoto":"(here photo url)"}
```

how can I get only the values of the keys? I want something like this:
John
1234
Jonny
student
(here photo url)

Thanks for helpers:)

Comment: please post sample inputs.

Comment: In your input data is there every any objects as a value to a key?  Or will the format **always** be {key:exact value,key:exact value}

Comment: You can use the split-method with comma to get the key-value-pairs. After that you can use the split-method with colon to get the values.

Comment: @IQV What if a key or value contains a comma and/or colon?  (Trick question;  the answer is, regular expressions cannot be used to parse JSON.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each row is a complete JSON object. You can use Gson JSON parser.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try {
  BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
  String line;
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Map map = gson.fromJson(line, Map.class);
    for(Object value : map.values()) {
      System.out.println(value);
    }
    sb.append(line);
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The format looks like JSON. If that's true, use any JSON parser you like and get only the keys.

E.g. org.json:json in Maven Central.

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java